# Custom cursor over mapped image

Tags: html, css

I want to add a custom cursor to my html picture gallery, where there I get a 'previous' or 'next' custom cursor over the left or right sides of the images.

I have tried adding a custom cursor through html and css (also tried built in cursors).
I had code that worked for this, but lost it in a hard drive crash.  I think the previous effort was in css.
I've spent ~8hrs research trying to rebuild this, now resorting to trial & error & error & ...

```css
img.pad {
  float: right;
  padding: 2px;
}

.lmap {
  cursor: cell, url(larrow.png)
}

.rmap {
  cursor: progress, url(rarrow.png), auto
}
```

```html
<img usemap="#imap" class="pad" src="img_0001.jpg" width="850" height="638" title="img_0001.jpg">
<p>
  <map name="imap"><area shape="rect" class="lmap" coords="0,0,340,637" cursor= copy href="P001.html" >
    <area shape="rect" class="rmap" coords="510,0,849,637" href="P003.html"></map>
```

I get no err msg & nothing beyond the (default) finger when hovering over the linked portions of the image.

The linkage works (even with bad cursor code), but I would like to get the cursor part running again.

I know the code is butchered, but I have tried many versions, arrgh!  I really want the png images, per the css section.

Comment: Is your `larrow.png` and `rarrow.png` in the same folder as you CSS file?

Comment: All css, html, png...same folder.  Multiple html share same css & cursor files.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.lmap {
  cursor: url(larrow.png), cell;
}

.rmap {
  cursor: url(rarrow.png), progress;
}
```

The url declaration should be first, while the other values are used as a fallback in case the url doesn't work. It doesn't make any sense to have the url as a fallback to a native value, as a browser will never choose to fallback to url value.

More info on cursor CSS [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor).

Comment: The problem seems to be with my png, I get the cell & progress cursors with your help.

Comment: How large are the png's? There is a dimension limit for cursors placed by browsers.

"In Gecko (Firefox) the limit of the cursor size is 128×128px. Larger cursor images are ignored. However, you should limit yourself to the size 32×32 for maximum compatibility with operating systems and platforms."

From (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Basic_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property)

Comment: I've tried different sizes down t0 32x32 pixels & different extensions png, jpg, gif & .cur.